# Limit the number of Pedestrian in service 'queue'?

Tags: anylogic

I have a simple model which has two Pedestrian Service blocks after one another. Is there a way to limit the queue for a service so it has a 'knock-back effect' on the queue/path area before?

[image]

I assume you can add a wait block before every ped-service that frees an agent if the ped-service queue is below a certain length. But, that seems a little messy (maybe a limitation of the pedestrian library) - would be keen to hear what best practices are from the experts (*cough* Ben & Felipe) :)

Comment: Why not to use regular queue with capacity=x?

Comment: I did give that ago, however, I can't get the passenger to walk along the snaking disney queue when I use a normal queue block. 

https://imgur.com/a/KOxdWur

Comment: what is a knock-back effect? if there's no space in the second service.. what do you want the pedestrians to do?

Comment: I want the pedestrians to stay on the snake path if the number of peds on the service block is more than 7.

Comment: Maybe I better way to word it would be: do not let agents leave their current service block if the queue of the service they are going to next is over a set capacity. 

Basically to prevent the pedestrians grouping at the second service block queue. 
https://imgur.com/a/YbUS5P0

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple wait or queue block before the service block and only let them exit the queue if the pedestrians in the service blocks are below a threshold.

You need to implement the release logic in the on enter for the queue
[image]

as well as for the exit at the service block
[image]

But, in order to make your snake path act as a queue you will need to add walls around it, else as per your example the pedestrians will group around the end of the path in a bunch. You will also need to set your pedestrain width to just more than half your path width to ensure they don't bunch inside the path

[image]